# “I remember him as an old man with a snowy-white (= pure white) beard”

Tags: modifiers

> I remember him as an old man with a snowy-white beard.

I want to modify “snowy”. Should I use an adjective (“pure-snowy white beard”) or an adverb (“purely-snowy white beard”)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those modifiers modify "snowy". "Pure" (along with "snowy") modifies "white". "Purely" modifies "snowy-white".

The only type of adverb I can think of that would modify "snowy" would be an adverb of degree, like "very", "nearly", or "somewhat".

Either way, there would be no hyphen before "snowy".

Comment: Then I don't understand your question at all. Snow isn't dark, and neither is the colour white, so neither "dark snowy white" nor "darkly snowy white" make sense. Either way, there's no hyphens.

Comment: I understand what you mean, so I fixed that.